# javamelody 1.58 security does not working in tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Javamelody is upgraded to 1.58 from 1.42 but container managed security (web.xml) does not work in tomcat8 but in tomcat9 it is working fine. How to fix this issue?

Taken following steps to upgrade javamelody.

Download javamelody.zip
Copy the files javamelody.jar and jrobin-x.jar, located at the root of the supplied javamelody.zip file, to the WEB-INF/lib directory of the war of the web app to monitor.

Put the following tag in web.xml of application.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>authorized-users</param-name>
        <param-value>user:pwd</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Create file named monitoring-spring.xml with the below code in path WEB-INF/classes/net/bull/javamelody/monitoring-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="monitoringAdvisor" class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringAdvisor">
        <property name="pointcut">
            <bean class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoredWithAnnotationPointcut"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"/>

    <bean id="springDataSourceBeanPostProcessor" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceBeanPostProcessor">
        <!--
        <property name="excludedDatasources">
            <set>
                <value>excludedDataSourceName</value>
            </set>
        </property>
        -->
    </bean>

    <!--
    <bean id="wrappedDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetName" value="targetDataSource" />
    </bean>
    -->
</beans>
```

File path is configure as context-param in web.xml of application like this :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

<param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext/**/*.xml    classpath:net/bull/javamelody/monitoring-spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param> 



And also when open monitoring in tomcat9 the correct and latest version is showing but not in tomcat8 and I am using java 8.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (JavaMelody 1.59 and Tomcat 8.0.23).
All init-param settings in web.xml for javamelody filter did not apply.

I had to add version attribute to web-app element in web.xml of application and set it to 3.1 (**version="3.1"**).

web.xml:

```
 <web-app 
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
       version="3.1"
       metadata-complete="true">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>authorized-users</param-name>
            <param-value>user:pwd</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
</web-app>
```